# Take a screen shot and save to desktop with current time as the name

Tags: applescript, screenshot

I am trying to make a script that will take a screen shot, save the image to the desktop, and name it the date. Similar to what would happen if I used cmd + shift + 3. The only issue is the name of the image is only "Screen" instead of the entire name I specified. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
on run
    set theDesktop to POSIX path of (path to desktop as string)
    set theCurrentDate to current date
    set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture " & theDesktop & "Screen Shot" & theCurrentDate & ".png"
    do shell script shellCommand
end run
```

Comment: I just did a script for something very similar. I didn't bother to give the full path name for "screencapture" and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the complete file path in double quotes, like this:

```
on run
    set theDesktop to POSIX path of (path to desktop as string)
    set theCurrentDate to current date
    set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture \"" & theDesktop & "Screen Shot" & theCurrentDate & ".png\""
    do shell script shellCommand
end run
```

The file name contains white space, hence, in your version, the command line interprets it as multiple arguments to `/usr/sbin/screencapture`.

Comment: Thanks! Im always surprised how difficult problems have such simple answers.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to pass the path above is by using quoted form of:

```
on run
    set theDesktop to POSIX path of (path to desktop as string)
    set theCurrentDate to current date
    set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture " & quoted form of (theDesktop & "Screen Shot" & theCurrentDate & ".png")
    do shell script shellCommand
end run
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer: much more elegant way also. (Note the blank space at the end of `"/usr/sbin/screencapture "` since Terminal separates variables using blank spaces)

Answer (score 1):

I just use a shell command like this:

```
screencapture -i ~/Desktop/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png
```

`-i` is interactive mode (like ⇧⌘4). The default file name format is like this on my installation:

```
date '+Screen Shot %Y-%m-%d at %-H.%M.%S %p.png'
```

See `man screencapture` and `man strftime`.

If you use AppleScript, the run handler is not needed, `/usr/sbin/` is on the path by default, and you can escape arguments with `quoted form of`.

```
"Screen Shot " & (current date) & ".png"
do shell script "screencapture ~/Desktop/" & quoted form of result
```

If the file name looks like `Screen Shot Wednesday, May 29, 2013 4/47/15 AM.png` in Finder, it's because HFS uses colon as a pathname separator. `:` in shells appears as `/` in Finder and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Emulate your keyboard:

```
-- Take Screenshot
tell application "System Events"
    -- Shift-Command-3
    key code 20 using {shift down, command down}
end tell
```

key code 20 is the same as number 3

Result:

```
Screen Shot 2018-11-18 at 12.47.39 pm
```

Complete list of key codes can be found here:

https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes